# Scroll bar CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an animation for a scroll bar in my navbar. The idea is that the user initially sees 'display one'at the center of the screen until it moves away and goes invisible. A new text (display two) moves into its position and the cycle repeats. I feel like I'm achieving this very crudely which requires a lot of manual adjustments. Even though I achieved the necessary animation the in code attached below, is there any optimized method to achieve this?

```css
.display-one {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(175%);
  animation: moveout 15s infinite;
}

@keyframes moveout {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(175%)
  }
  49% {
    transform: translateX(175%)
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-500%);
  }
  99% {
    transform: translateX(-500%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(175%);
  }
}

.display-two {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  transform: translateX(410%);
  animation: movein 15s infinite;
}

@keyframes movein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(410%)
  }
  49% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(410%)
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(138%)
  }
  99% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(138%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(410%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="master-mast">
  <div class="display-one  ">
    <span>Test1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="display-two ">
    <span>Test2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your html code? Please provide a workable example...

Comment: Hey, I added the HTML.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you right, you basically want these animations to play as the user scrolls in the navbar normally, correct? Sort of like transitioning between elements as you scroll (horizontally at that, I'm guessing). You throwing in "scroll bar" is kinda confusing, since you're not actually doing anything with the scroll bar in your example. Either way though, making animations work with dynamic content is practically impossible without also making use of JavaScript, so, just a heads up on that.